# Batch converting swf to png

Tags: image-processing

I have a folder with a lot of swf files. They are named that way: `fis1.swf; fis2.swf; fis3.swf; ... fis20.swf`. I want to convert all of them into png files. I know it can be done with swfrender from swftools, but it only renders one file per time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably use `find` to do this:

```
find -iname 'fis*.swf' -exec swfrender "{}" -o "{}.png" \;
```

But you could probably use other sorts of loops:

```
for f in fis{1..20}.swf; do
    swfrender "$f" -o "$f.png"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

First make a new file and call it for example `swfconvert`

```
gedit swfconvert
```

Paste the code below into it:

```
for img in *.swf; 
do 
 swfrender "$img" -o "$img.png"
done
```

Save and close. Then run the new batch from terminal:

```
sh swfconvert
```

This script should work for all swf files in a given directory. It should be saved in the same directory where your .swf files reside

Comment: Note: You don't need to `touch swfconvert`. Gedit will automatically create the file after saving.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Oli answer, you can also use `convert` tool from `imagemagick` set.

```
for f in fis{1..20}; do
convert $f.swf $f.png
done
```

This can be put into single line as

```
for f in fis{1..20}; do convert $f.swf $f.png; done
```